# Ways to imply return values are not meant to be stored

Tags: c++, c++17, methodology

We can use `nodiscard` attribute to imply that the return value of a function should not be discarded. Are there any attribute (or other ways) to imply some *opposite* semantics: the return value of the function should only be used temporarily (by "temporary" I mean, not to assign to any variable except local ones)?

As the purpose may not be immediately clear, consider I have a class `FooHolder` that holds resources `Foo`; calling `FooHolder::getFoo()` returns the `Foo` it is *currently* holding:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo& bar() { /* do something */ return *this; }
    const Foo& far() const { /* do something else */ return *this; }
};

class FooHolder {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> _foo { nullptr };

public:
    FooHolder(): _foo(std::make_shared<Foo>()) {}

    Foo& getFoo() { return *_foo; }
    const Foo& getFoo() const { return *_foo; }
};
```

And we may use it in many ways:

```cpp
// Others may try storing some status:
Foo* g_foo = nullptr;

int main() {
    FooHolder foo_holder {};

    // I want to support this:
    foo_holder.getFoo().bar().far() /* chained calls... */ ;

    // Also, maybe this:
    auto& local_foo = foo_holder.getFoo();
    local_foo.bar();
    local_foo.far();

    // But not this, because the Foo instance that FooHolder holds may perish:
    static Foo& static_foo = foo_holder.getFoo();

    // Nor this:
    g_foo = &local_foo;

    return 0;
}
```

So are there ways to prevent (or at least warn about) storing the return value of `FooHolder::getFoo()`? Or, is it bad practice to return resources by reference?

Comment: why encapsulate `Foo` in a `FooHolder` just to immedately give direct access to the `Foo` ? If `FooHolder`s methods return a `FooHolder` and if there is a `FooHolder::bar` and `FooHolder::far` then the caller needs not get their hands on the contained `Foo`

Comment: If I understand your position correctly (not guaranteed) you may be able to use `std::weak_ptr` so you can always safely check if your resource still exists before using it - or else obtain a fresh one.

Comment: This looks to me like a design problem. Why not return a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: From what you intend to allow it seems you might avoid reading `FooHolder::_foo` in general and make only the member functions which should be called visible: `FooHolder::bar() { _foo.bar(); }`

Comment: You cannot differentiate `auto& local_foo = foo_holder.getFoo(); /*maybe ok*/` from `static Foo& static_foo = foo_holder.getFoo(); /*Wrong*/`.

Comment: You can enforce the chain call usage by returning rvalue reference and rvalue qualify `Foo`'s methods.

Comment: @zdf I've considered returning `shared_ptr` but I think the `.` operator to access chained calls maybe more elegant. And there are not "shared references". Also, the caller storing a `shared_ptr` actually prolonged the life of the underlying object (obtaining pointer is owning).

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to an object's data in the first place?   The caller is responsible for ensuring the reference doesn't dangle (e.g. by ensuring the object exists as long as the reference does, or that no operations on the object change its state).   If you can't rely on the caller executing that responsibility, don't return a raw reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] is it bad practice to return resources by reference?

It depends. There are many examples of methods that return non-const references and they are all fine. For example consider standard container element accessors. However, they are not meant for encapsulation. `std::vector::operator[]` is not meant to hide the elements from the caller, it is meant to provide direct access to it. Returning a non-const reference is not encapsulation! It is the opposite. Note that `std::vector`  even grants you access to its `data()`. Thats not encapsulation either, it is relying on the user to not `delete[] some_vect.data()` or do other wrong stuff that would break the vector.

You want `FooHolder` to encapsulate the contained `Foo`.

This is opposing requirements.

You have basically two choices: A) The caller knows what they are doing. They read documentation. They know that they are not supposed to use `FooHolder::getFoo` in the wrong way. B) use proper encapsulation: Never give the caller direct access to a non-const `Foo`:

```
class FooHolder {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> _foo { nullptr };

public:
    FooHolder(): _foo(std::make_shared<Foo>()) {}

    // nope // Foo& getFoo() { return *_foo; }
    // maybe // const Foo& getFoo() const { return *_foo; }
    
    FooHolder& bar() { 
            _foo->bar();
            return *this;
    }
    // ..same for far() ...
};
```

Note that A) is a viable solution. Consider that also things like `std::shared_ptr` can be used terribly wrong. Users are expected to know how to use it right. The difference is that `std::shared_ptr` is a standard type with plenty of documentation. Hence, you should think twice if this is the way to go.

---

> So are there ways to prevent (or at least warn about) storing the return value of FooHolder::getFoo()?

No. Once you returned a non-const reference all bets are off. `FooHolder` is no longer in control of what the caller can do with that reference. You can prevent copies or moves but you cannot prevent holding on to a reference.

Comment: Wow that's a thorough explanation. But we would have to proxy *every* method that `Foo` exposes, and maybe in the future `Foo` is extended but `FooHolder` isn't, is there better way to handle this extra complicity?

Comment: @Oasin there is too little context to propose a better way. From what you posted it seems like `using FooHolder = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;` would be the easiest to avoid all the "extra complexity"